# Identifying Literary Devices ~ Synecdoche or Pun?

Tags: puns, literary-device, synecdoche

> She would step out of the river, dry in the sun for five minutes and climb back into the car among the **shocked eyeballs of her companions.**

Is the emphasized phrase an example of a synecdoche or a pun?

My interpretation: It's a synecdoche since the sentence states that the woman literally climbs the car "among the shocked eyeballs of her companions." I am visualizing the woman actually entering the car and sitting next to eyeballs. In this case, eyeballs are used to refer to the people in the car; the same as *hard hats* may refer to *construction workers*.

Am I right, or any other suggestions/interpretations?

Comment: The clinical version would be '... among / right in front of her companions with their shocked expressions.' 'Eyeballs' is arguably a synechdoche, arguably metonymy. 'Among the shocked expressions ...' is also arguably synechdoche. Do paired examples of synechdoche constitute surrealism?

Comment: What do you think the pun might be?

Comment: I guess if the woman were a live wire, "shocked eyeballs" might be a pun.

Comment: I can’t answer what you asked and please be aware that shocked or not, eyeballs are clearly not used to refer to the people in the car in the same way as "hard hats" might refer to "construction workers."

The comparison would be not to “hard hats” but to "hard hats of the construction workers." Do you think that would work?